# WPF ListView with extra column

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` defined as follow:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
          <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                     <GridView.Columns>
                          <GridViewColumn Header="Camera" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CameraName}" />
                           <GridViewColumn Header="Stato">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <svgc:SvgViewbox x:Name="svgIcon" Height="20"  Width="20" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                            <customUserControl:ExtendedBinding
                                                   Source="{Binding ElementName=svgIcon, Path=Source, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                   Target="{Binding Path=IsNotConnected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToSvgPathConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="Retry" Width="46" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotConnected}" Click="TryReconnection_Onclick"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that the `ListView` shown has one extra column and I can't understand the reason why. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fit your column to the exact size you need by "Auto" Width:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Camera" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CameraName}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stato">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Retry" Width="46"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added Width="Auto" to each columns, but nothing changes.

Comment: Not to each column, to the whole ListView like I did. I will update the answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't understand that I had to put the ListView in a Grid. Thanks, it works!